# QTP adds object to local repository while doing Update Run mode

Tags: automation, qtp

I have created total 50 test scripts. All these scripts use almost same objects so I have created a Shared Repository to ease the maintenance work.

But the problem is...
While executing scripts in Update Run mode, QTP adds some objects in local repository even if they are present there in Shared Repository. I have checked properties of these newly added objects and there are no change in that too.

Anybody please tell me the logic QTP uses to decided whether to add a object to local repository or not.
Also tell me a solution so that no object is added to the local repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things at work here.

1. QTP opens Shared Object Repositories (SORs) in read only mode
   since SORs are by definition shared, QTP wants to make sure that
   when someone makes a change to a SOR he is aware that many tests may
   be affected. Therefore in order to edit a SOR you have to use the
   Object Repository Manger and no changes are made to a SOR
   automatically (*Update Run Mode* or *Maintenance Run Mode*)
2. When adding an object to the object repository QTP first checks if the object already exists (by comparing properties) if it does it reuses the existing object and doesn't make a new entry.

This explains why you're getting objects in the *Local Object Repository* (LOR) and not the SOR, (I'm not sure if having unmodified objects added to the LOR is the correct behaviour or not).

In order to propagate the changes after the *Update Run Mode* you should export the LOR to a new SOR and then merge it with your existing SOR.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar kind of problem. While execurting script qtp was not identifying an object although object was present in shared OR and it was highlighting in application. when i checked in maintenance run mode there was a change in one prperty value which i updated in shared OR. The problem was I spy on that object and qtp saved it in local OR. so next time when i run the script it was refering from local OR and script was failing. so i deleted object (which was showing as Local) from object repository window  , then it displayed the same object of shared OR (which was QC path)